# Excel IsError equivalent function in C#

Tags: c#, excel

Is there a function in c# that can help to check if the statement is going to return error.

I am aware about `try{} catch{}` but we can't use it in condition checking. For example:

```
var opertionResult = SomeRestFunction.Trigger();
string ServerResponse = if(operationResult != null)
{
    if(operationResult.Response != null)
    {
        operationResult.Response.ResponseText;
    }
    Else
    {
        "Null";
    }
}
Else
{ "Null"; }
```

In the example above, I need to perform multiple checks to validate the `operationResult` object properties at multiple levels due to nested objects in it, to determine the final value I want to read and consume as server response value.

If we have some thing like `IsError()` function in Excel, we can simply try to read the final object property i.e. `operationResult.Response.ResponseText;` inside of that function and if any of the parent object is null and it has to throw an error it will return false and we can return the value from the else block as shown in the hypothetical example below:

```
var opertionResult = SomeRestFunction.Trigger();
string ServerResponse = IsError(operationResult.Response.ResponseText)? "Null": operationResult.Response.ResponseText;
```

So, do we have something like this in C#? Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using c# 6 or newer version then you can use [null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) & [null-coalescing-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operator like below.

Here you need to place `?` to check if object is `null` or not. If object is `null` then it will not perform any further check and return `null`. And `null-coalescing-operator` (`??`) will be used to check if value is `null` then it will return value provided afer `??`.

```
string ServerResponse = SomeRestFunction.Trigger()?.Response?.ResponseText ?? "Null";
```